Is this Piston Setup Impossible to Achieve with Object Constraints?
I have this piston setup, and I am using object constraints to get it so I can move the two mounts wherever I want, with the other objects rotating to make the piston work. I have done this already, but this type of design seems impossible to get to work without creating a dependency cycle.
If anyone has created this setup before, I would love to know how. I am open to using bones instead of object constraints, its just that parenting the mounts to something is so easy to do.

file:

Can the mounts (rectangular end parts) rotate or can they just translate ? In your configuration, top and bottom axes are aligned or perpendicular, what make things easier with "just" 6 degrees of freedom (2*3) instead of 12...

@StefLAncien I want them to be able to rotate, because the positions I want them in do not have their axis aligned. I do know that if they shared an axis, I could just have the pistons point to the mounts and that would get rid of the loop. I believe this is just not possible, though I have seen a solution that "hides" the problem https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-rig-this-piece-for-a-stewart-platform/1320396/3 . This one uses a stretch to constraint on the bones, and it hides the deformation happening at the bases.
